# Bottom Collection view spacing issues, I want to remove the blue spacing

Tags: ios, swift, collections

I am getting the space between the cells (marked with blue color):

[image]

```dart
extension ProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == self.humanCollectionView {
            let screenWidth = humanCollectionView.bounds.width
            return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3-0, height: screenWidth/3-0)
            
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
                UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                return 0
            }
            
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
                UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                return 0
            }
            
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
                return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            }
        }
```

Comment: is that mcOs or landscape mode of simulator?

Comment: It should be landscape since the question is tagged iOS

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed it is phone 13

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter it is iPhone 13

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring the delegate functions inside `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath)` delegate method?

Try to do like this:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileVC: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //remember to set the delegates
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        //this is optional just to test that it is working
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}

extension ProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //this is just a test number, here you should return the number of your items
        return 20
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //you should set reuseIndetifier in storyboard or in code if you create your collectionView programmatically
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        //again this is just a placeholder color to see that it's working
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        //be sure to use floor or to use a number of items that perfectly fits the width of collectionView
        return CGSize(width: floor(screenWidth/3), height: floor(screenWidth/3))
    }
            
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
        UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
        UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

I want to add that if the width of your collectionView is not perfectly divisible by 3, you will always have some gap between the cells. You should do the math by yourself for each device width and choose a proper number of cells for the width. For example for a screen with aspect ratio like iPhone X, I would use 3 cells when in portrait and 4 cells when in landscape.

You can do like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    let screenHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
    let numberOfCells : CGFloat = screenWidth > screenHeight ? 4 : 3
    return CGSize(width: floor(screenWidth/numberOfCells), height: floor(screenWidth/numberOfCells))
}
```